# Oracle SQL - AVG function invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

and good afternoon. Happy to post I haven't needed to post any questions in a bit and have instead started answering. Woo :)

Anyway, my problem here is that I am trying to write a subquery that pulls my vendor, their part, and how much their part is. The vendor may supply the part many times, so I want to AVERAGE the price of the part. Later, I am looking to see about any problem notices against those parts. However, I can't reference the field that I am averaging later on. What do I do?

The SQL looks as follows and is in ORACLE syntax:

```
WITH
PartVendor AS
(
SELECT PARTNAME, PARTNUM, AVG(PARTPRICE), VENDNAME, VENDNUM
FROM PARTBL
    INNER JOIN VENDTBL ON VENDNUM = PARTVENDNUM
GROUP BY PARTNAME, PARTNUM, VENDNAME, VENDNUM
),

PartProbs AS
(
SELECT PartVendor.*, PROBNUM, PROBDESC
FROM PartVendor
    INNER JOIN PROBTBL ON PARTNUM = PROBPARTNUM
)

SELECT *
FROM PartProbs
```

Later on, I will do more. But I keep getting an error on PARTPRICE telling me that it is an invalid identifier. Can anybody help?

Comment: I don't see the column list for your cte.  `WITH cte_name (column_list) AS ( ...)`

Comment: I don't know what cte is, but I've never used WITH AS that way before and I've been using it for subqueries for awhile. @Eric

Comment: Are you sure that one of your tables, `PARTBL` and `VENDTBL`, has a column `PARTPRICE`? If so, perhaps it was declared using double-quotes, as in `"PartPrice"` - which then makes it mandatory that it be called `"PartPrice"` whenever it is referenced?

Comment: @mathguy no I'm positive the PARTBL has a column PARTPRICE...I watched it be developed. The solution below worked fine. If I DIDN'T use the aggregate function, it would work, but my problem was how to reference the aggregated column outside of the subquery. When I first tried using an alias I used "" to name it, which I guess made it ambiguous because I couldn't reference it in the next subquery.

Comment: I got it as soon as you Commented under Gordon's answer. You created the confusion because you posted, in your original question, what you **said** was your code (which caused the error). But the error was caused by the double quotes, which you left out for some reason. Now the question and the Correct Answer are both confusing and misleading. You could help by editing your original question to add back the double quotes that were causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name all columns in the CTE:

```
WITH PartVendor AS (
      SELECT PARTNAME, PARTNUM, AVG(PARTPRICE) as AVG_PARTPRICE, VENDNAME, VENDNUM
      FROM PARTBL INNER JOIN
           VENDTBL ON VENDNUM = PARTVENDNUM
      GROUP BY PARTNAME, PARTNUM, VENDNAME, VENDNUM
     ),
     . . .
```

Comment: Can I then refer to AVG_PARTPRICE in a later subquery?

Comment: I agree with your statement as "sound advice", but it does **not** explain the error; the syntax, even with function calls that are not given an alias, is correct (at least in Oracle), even if it is a bad practice.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff it worked perfectly, thank you!! I was previously using double quotes to name aliases and that is why it didn't work when I referenced it outside. I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Lol - so that was NOT the issue, the issue was the double quotes. This will be **very** helpful to others who will have the same question in the future.